# Keystore and Private Keys... Explain in Simple Terms, Please

Tags: android, android-keystore

I understand they are used to sign and verify the authenticity of one's work, yet I still don't fully understand the roles they play. Google's dev guide just kind of says "you need these." I'm looking for an explanation, maybe in terms of something else in life I'm familiar with, so that I can understand them at a high level. I don't exactly have a computer science background.

Here's what I think they are and you can tell me if I'm right.

The `keystore` is like the document of authenticity for my app and my `private key` is like my private seal on it. Therefore, if I develop multiple apps, each will have a `keystore`, which I'll sign with the same `private key`. Right??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The keystore is basically the database of your private keys. You can have multiple keys stored in your key store. The private key is what you use to sign the app with, and because nobody else will have your private key, nobody else can make fake apps with your company, account, etc.

Comment: So I sign my app with my private key, which adds that private key to my keystore? I'm afraid I still don't understand. Does the keystore also define the packages that my private key has authorized? Is it like the keystore holds Package1 and Package2 and the fact that I've signed each of them with my private key?

Comment: The key store just holds your keys. Your keystore doesn't define the apps. It just is a security measure to make sure you are the true author of an app. You can also use the same private key for all of your apps... The private key contains your name, country, company name, etc. The only reason to use more than one private key might be if you work for more than one company.

Comment: So it just holds my private keys? So if I have one private key it simply holds that one key. And then my app is signed using that key in the keystore. Yeah?

Answer (score 0):

You can use same keystore and private key for each of your apps. There is no need to create separate keystore/privatekey for each app.

During building production apk your IDE/building system will use private key from your keystore in order to sign files inside this apk. Thanks to that only you will be able to update app to the Play Store (Google will check if certificate fingerprints are the same).